# Google Sheets QUERY IMPORTRANGE is merging first and second rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a company that I work for, I have two Google Sheets. In one of them (let's call it "**Destination**"), I am trying to use QUERY+IMPORTRANGE to bring the values from the other (let's call it "**Origin**").

My problem is that in the first row of **Destination**, the values of the cells are a merger of the values of the first and second rows of **Origin**.

For example, the value in cell B1 of **Destination** should be the value of cell B1 in **Origin**. However, it is actually the values of B1 and B2 of **Origin**. The same happens for every single cell in the first row.

- Origin B1: milk
- Origin B2: water
- Destination B1 (desired value): milk
- Destination B1 (value that is appearing): milk water

The only problem is with the first two rows of **Origin**. All the other rows are fine (meaning that row 2 in **Destination** is row 3 of **Origin**, row 3 in **Destination** is row 4 of **Origin**, and so on).

I am using the following formula:

```
=QUERY( {IMPORTRANGE("URL";"'Sheet1'!A1:CW")} ; "Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

I have discovered that when I use A1:AO as the interval in IMPORTRANGE, the problem doesn't happen. However, when I use it from A1:AP and onwards, the problem appears.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query to specify 1 for the header parameter:

```
=QUERY( {IMPORTRANGE("URL";"'Sheet1'!A1:CW")} ; "Select * where Col1 is not null",1)
```

or 0 if i'm misunderstanding the data layout...

```
=QUERY( {IMPORTRANGE("URL";"'Sheet1'!A1:CW")} ; "Select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

Comment: I tried with both 1 and 0, and both times it worked! Thank you very much! Could you please explain to me what does this 1 or 0 do? I am trying to read the documentation of the QUERY function and I understand that it is something related to the header, but I don't understand what exactly.

Comment: @RafaelPinheiro the explanation depends slightly on what your data actually looks like.  is the 1st row of the source data "headers" or "values"?

Comment: They are values!

Comment: @RafaelPinheiro then it should be be 0 for that third parameter in the query, not 1.

the query() function allows you to specify how many of the rows you're giving it to "analyze" are header rows rather than value rows.  If you don't specify, it does it's best to guess.  The most common situation is 1 header row on a dataset.  For whatever reason, when you started adding additional columns, the query thought there might be 2 header rows.  Whenever query thinks (or is told) there are more than one header row, it merges them together.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the solution and for the explanation, Matt! I had been trying to solve this for hours! :)